# How To Achieve Communication Between Multiple Classes?

Tags: c#

Imagine there are separate main two classes which are:

- `Storage` Class
- `System` Class

WHERE, `Storage`class is a class used for getting and setting data (container for data value like properties)
WHERE, `System` class is a class derived from `Storage` used as container for multiple sub systems that are:

- `Read System`

WHERE, `Read System` is a subclass (AND inner class of `System`) derived from the base class `System`, it's main purpose is to GET values from `Storage` (class) and return the value.

There is main class for managing all of these classes called `ManagerSystem` for communication.
It is not derived from `System`, it is separate class.

If I want to get the `Name` property, I would need to call method from `ManagerSystem`, `ManagerSystem` would then talk to `System` and asked it to get name.

`System` would then talk to its child class, `Read System` to get name. `Read System` would finally get the name property from `Storage` class.

Is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

Simple Example

- 1. The user wants to get the name property. The user calls the method GetName() in ManagerSystem class.
- 2. ManagerSystem will notify System to let them know that the user need a name property.
- 3. System will then notify its child class (Read System) to get the name property. System cannot get name property on its own without Read System.
- 4. ReadSystem will get the name property from Storage Class.

NOTE:
ManagerSystem can only communicate with System. It cannot communicate with Storage directly.
System can only communicate with child classes (ReadSystem). It cannot directly communicate with Storage

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Oberserver pattern?
I think this is the closest thing to what you want. 
It will allow classes to inform each other, that they have done something. And then the observers can act also.

Comment: its really hard to follow what you are saying could you not simple have an example of what you want and then explain the problem.

Comment: also what and where does protected  class "can only be accessed from with in the class or any object that inherits off of the class" come into this. aka what the is requirement they are protected, if that's limiting you then surely its the wrong access modifier level.

Comment: Hi, I edited an question for better understanding. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Could you do things any more complicated? Is that on purpose? Is there a deeper purpose of that all? Are you trying to implement some design pattern?

Comment: _"How To Achieve Communication Between Multiple Classes?"_ - Most of the time, "communication" means "call a method ( passing 0 to N parameters and optionally getting a result back)" in this context.

Comment: Just trying to achieve security.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick some of the famous “GoF Design Patterns” to help in your design. They aren't the solution for all issues but those ideas are from very clever people that faced similar problems.

Two Design Pattern (DP) come to my mind for you issue :

- Mediator (see usefull ressource and C# code at [refactoring guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/mediator))
- Visitor (see usefull ressource and C# code at [refactoring guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor))

It's not easy to implement but you can try to make the both. You will learn a lot !
Take care